# Django signals duplicate with unique dispatch id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a problem with duplicate signals. I have looked-up the [relevant part of Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals) and [a similar question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813156/django-signals-how-to-create-a-unique-dispatch-id) but I still can't get it working right - i.e. the action that I have planned (creation on an ActivityLog entry) is actually happening 4 times :/

I have added the `dispatch_uid` and the problem still persists, so I guess I'm doing something wrong. Can you please hint me to the error?

Here's my code:

`signals.py`

```
from patient.models import Patient
from .models import ActivityLog

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Patient)
def create_new_patient(sender, instance, **kwargs):


    ActivityLog.objects.create(
        user=instance.created_by_user,
        event='created a new patient',
        patient_id=instance.patient_id
    )
```

and this is it's usage in the `patient.apps` module:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

app_name = "patient"


class PatientConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'patient'
    verbose_name = "Patients"

    def ready(self):
        from activity_logger.signals import create_new_patient
        print('Patient APP is ready!')
        pre_save.connect(create_new_patient, sender='patient.Patient', dispatch_uid='patient')
```

The print `Patient APP is ready!` does appear twice, and the object gets created 4 times, despite setting the `dispatch_uid`. What have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1):

The `@receiver(Signal,...)` decorator is a shortcut for `Signal.connect(...)`, so you indeed register your `create_new_patient` handler twice (once thru `@receiver` when importing your `signals` module, the second time with `pre_save.connect()`.

Solution : in your `App.ready()` method, you should just import your app's `signal.py` module. This will trigger the registration of the handlers decorated with `@receiver`.

Comment: Hi, @bruno desthuilliers great answer! Indeed - that reduced the numer of created ActivityLogs objects to ... just 2 (previously 4). The reason is that the ready() function is triggered twice (e.g. the 'Patient APP is ready' appears twice). Any idea why ?

Comment: @user1544500 Nope, and I'd like to know how you managed to get this happening actually <g>. Hint: add a debugger breakpoint in your `App.ready` method and inspect the call stack in the first and second call.